# customize $singularHumanName in templates

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have custom template - to translate autogenerated views. There is for example a line:

```
echo "<?php echo \$this->Html->link(__('Lista " . $pluralHumanName . "'), array('action' => 'index')); ?>";
```

My models have english names (as cake's convention wants) but I want to use translated model names in auto created views. For example in Title Model I was trying to declare:

```
$pluralHumanName = 'Stanowiska';
```

but generated view files always have english name... and I have to translate each file manually. Is there a way to translate/change $singularHumanName and $pluralHumanName ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you double-translating then?

```
 __('Lista " . $pluralHumanName . "')
```

the __() already translates. So you try to translate your translated string a second time (without having the translated strings in your po then of course).

You should stick with the english words in your __() and then put your "Lista" and other translated strings in your po file.

Or just:

```
'Lista " . __($pluralHumanName) . "'
```

without the `__()` around. The `__()` for $pluralHumanName, though, translates right away in your template and will become the your desired name (hardcoded). But as I mentioned above, you usually don't go that way!